# Could anybody explain inside functioning of .replace method in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

I want to solve a problem which takes two inputs, 1st is a string and 2nd is it's substring. Then i have to remove all occurences of the substring in the string and return the remaining part of string.
Without using **replace method**.
Now if I know the length of substring, it's doable, but what if the length is unknown?
Thanks
Here's my answer, it fails when there are multiple occurrences of substring in the string. Now it works correctly.

```
inputS=input('string?')
inputSub=input('substring?')
s=list(inputS)
sub=list(inputSub)
print(sub)
z=len(s)-len(sub)+1
y=len(sub)
def remove_sub():
    li=[]       #index at which substring is present
    for x in range(z):
        if s[x]==sub[0]:
            if y==1:
                li.append(x)
                continue
            for temp in range(1,y):
                if s[x+temp]==sub[temp]:
                    temp+=1
                    if temp==y:
                        li.append(x)
                    else:
                        print(x)
        else:
            continue
    return(li)
li=remove_sub()
print(li)
temp2=0
for i in range(len(li)): #removing substring
    del s[li[i]+temp2:(li[i]+y+temp2)]
    temp2-=(y)
out=''.join(s)
print(out)
```

Comment: if string="bananaann" and substring="an" , "ban" should be returned.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean by "if the length of substring is unknown"? The substring is an input, hence how can you not know its length? Is it a constraint that you don't use it?

Comment: I meant to say if the substring is of variable length(unknown), versus fixed.

Comment: How would you do it if you knew the length?  Then perhaps we can help you change that approach

Answer (score 1):

This works and doesn't use `str.replace()`:

```
>>> "".join("bananaann".split("an")) 
'ban'
```

Put it in a new function and you're done.

```
def replace_(original, sub_from, sub_to=""):
    return sub_to.join(original.split(sub_from))

>>> replace_("bananaann", "an")
'ban'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    inputS=input('string?')
inputSub=input('substring?')
s=list(inputS)
sub=list(inputSub)
print(sub)
z=len(s)-len(sub)+1
y=len(sub)
def remove_sub():
    li=[]       #index at which substring is present
    for x in range(z):
        if s[x]==sub[0]:
            if y==1:
                li.append(x)
                continue
            for temp in range(1,y):
                if s[x+temp]==sub[temp]:
                    temp+=1
                    if temp==y:
                        li.append(x)
                    else:
                        print(x)
        else:
            continue
    return(li)
li=remove_sub()
print(li)
temp2=0
for i in range(len(li)): '''removing substrings, works even for multiple occurences'''
    del s[li[i]+temp2:(li[i]+y+temp2)]
    temp2-=(y)
out=''.join(s)
print(out)
```